# Python: comparing lists by rules

Tags: python, algorithm

Input data:

```
rules = (
    ("1|1": "A"),
    ("2|1": "B"),
    ("3|1": "C"),
    ("2|2": "X")
)

pattern = [[1,2,3], [7,8]]
```

I need a function to do this job for the below result:

```
list1 = [[1,3,4], [7,9]] # result: B
list2 = [[1,2,3], [7,9]] # result: C
list3 = [[0,5,4], [8,5]] # result: None
list4 = [[1,6,2], [7,8]] # result: X
list5 = [[1,6,2,5], [7,8]] # result: Error
```

Comment: Can you clarify the algorithm a bit? It's not clear to me what it is.

Comment: Definetly Need more informations about how it's suppose to work, and what it's about in order to help you..

Comment: Also, I'm voting to close as too localized because, as the description says, this question is "… only relevant to … an extraordinarily narrow situation not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet".

Comment: For instance, with `list1` we see 2 elements of `list1[0]` are in `pattern`, 1 element of `list1[1]` is in `pattern` list. So we should compare with `rules` to show the result.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain what is going on -- your description in the comment is far too cryptic for me to understand. Step through one of the examples step-by-step. (And heck, that might even be the best answer...)

Comment: You have to write your own function or class which is doing this. Should not be that difficult if you use a dictionary for the rules, instead of whatever it is. Compare each entry of a list with the entry in `pattern` and access the corresponding entry in `rules`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of functional Python:

```
>>> rules = {
    "1|1": "A",
    "2|1": "B",
    "3|1": "C",
    "2|2": "X"
}
>>> pattern = [[1,2,3], [7,8]]
>>> l = [[1,3,4], [7,9]]
>>> diffs = '|'.join(map(lambda x: str(len(set(x[0]) & set(x[1]))),
                         zip(pattern, l)))
>>> rules.get(diffs)
'B'
```

Works the same for the rest of lists.  Error handling is the exercice for you:)